# How to form dbPedia iSPARQL query (for wikipedia content)

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

Say I need to fetch content from wikipedia about all mountains. My target is to show initial paragraph, and an image from respective article (eg. [Monte Rosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Rosa) and [Vincent Pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_Pyramid).

I came to know about dbpedia, and with some research got to find that it provides live queries into wiki database directly.

I have 2 questions:

1 - I am finding it difficult how could I formulate my queries. I can't play around [iSPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/#). I tried following query but it throws error saying invalid xml.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Mountain FROM <http://dbpedia.org> WHERE {
  [] rdf:type ?Mountain 
}
```

2 - My requirement is to show only mountains that have at least 1 image (I need to show this image too). Now the ones I listed above have images, but how could I be sure? Also, looking at both examples I see many fields differ in wiki articles - so for future extension it maybe quite difficult to fetch them.

I just want to reject those which do not have sufficient data or description.

How can I filter out mountains based on pictures present?

**UPDATE:**

My corrected query, which solves my first problem:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?description
WHERE {
?name rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Mountain>;
dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description .
}
```

Comment: The query you wrote wouldn't search for mountains; rather it says, "find me all the triples of the form '_ rdf:type ?x' and give me back the list of each ?x".  It's just asking for a list of types in the data.

Comment: ok, got my query correct and now it returns mountain list correctly. Edited the answer. Still, my 2nd problem remains.

Comment: My answer includes a query for `foaf:depiction` so that things without a depiction aren't included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also query dbpedia using its [SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) (less fancy than iSPARQL).  To find out more about what queries to write, take a look at the [DBpedia's datasets page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets).  The examples there show how one can select pages based on Wikipedia categories.  To select resources in the [Wikipedia Mountains category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aMountains), you can use the following query:

```
select ?mountain where {
  ?mountain a dbpedia-owl:Mountain .
}
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%3Fmountain+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fmountain+a+dbpedia-owl%3AMountain+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Once you have some of these links in hand, you can look at them in a web browser and see the data associated with them.  For instance the page for [Mount Everest](http://dbpedia.org/page/Mount_Everest) shows lots of properties.  For restricting results to those pages that have an image, you might be interested in the `dbpedia-owl:thumbnail` property, or perhaps better yet `foaf:depiction`.  For the introductory paragraph, you probably want something like the `dbpedia-owl:abstract`.  Using those, we can enhance the query from before.  The following query finds things in the category Stratovolcanoes with an abstract and an depiction.  Since StackOverflow is an English language site, I've restricted the abstracts to those in English.

```
select * where {
  ?mountain a dbpedia-owl:Mountain ;
            dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
            foaf:depiction ?depiction .
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"EN"))
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++select+%2a+where+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fmountain+a+dbpedia-owl%3AMountain+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract+%3Fabstract+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++foaf%3Adepiction+%3Fdepiction+.%0D%0A++++++FILTER%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%22EN%22%29%29%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++LIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks much, that cleared my query - upvoted too. As for curiosity - they seem to have parallel ways of querying - there is this page: http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/ - where very limited set of Things are included. On the other hand there are syntax like this (http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+*+WHERE+{%0D%0A%3Fsubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3ACar_manufacturers%3E.%0D%0A}+LIMIT+20) which directly queries wikipedia category. Which one is more exhaustive?

Comment: @NiravBhatt In the first draft of my answer, I used `dcterms:subject` and Wikipedia categories.  I think that's more exhaustive, but less useful because, e.g., the Mountains category doesn't contain any mountains, but rather a bunch of subcategories.  E.g., the categories for [Grand Monadnock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Monadnock) don't include **Mountains**, but rather the sub-sub-sub-subcategory, **Mountains of New Hampshire**.  The `dbpedia-owl` ontology classes seem much more useful, even if they won't have quite as much coverage.

Comment: Many thanks! Could you also try answering my newest query on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758089/sparql-queries-to-refer-to-other-resources?