# How to form SPARQL queries that refers to multiple resources

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

My question is a followup with [my first question about SPARQL here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721026/how-to-form-dbpedia-isparql-query-for-wikipedia-content/16721681#16721681).

My SPARQL query results for Mountain objects are [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?mountain%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Mountain%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:abstract%20?abstract%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf:depiction%20?depiction%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%28langMatches%28lang%28?abstract%29,%22EN%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).

From those results I picked a certain [object resource](http://dbpedia.org/page/Mont_Blanc).
Now I want to get values of "**is dbpedia-owl:highestPlace of**" records for this chosen Mountain object.

That is, names of mountain ranges for which **this mountain is highest place of**.

This is, as I figure, complex. Not only because I do not know the required syntax, but also I get two objects here.

- One of them is [Mont Blank Massif](http://dbpedia.org/page/Mont_Blanc_massif) which is of type "place".
- Another one is [Western Alps](http://dbpedia.org/page/Western_Alps) which is of type "mountain range" - my desired record.

I need record # 2 above but not 1. I know 1 is also relevant but sometimes it doesn't follow same pattern. Sometimes the records appear to be of YAGO type, which can be totally misleading. To be safe, I simply want to discard those records whenever there is type mismatch.

How can I form my SPARQL query to get these "**is dbpedia-owl:highestPlace of**" records and also have the type filtering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this query, note however that [Mont_Blanc_massif](http://dbpedia.org/page/Mont_Blanc_massif) in your example is both a `dbpedia-owl:Place` and a `dbpedia-owl:MountainRange`

```
select * where {
   ?place dbpedia-owl:highestPlace :Mont_Blanc.
   ?place rdf:type dbpedia-owl:MountainRange.
}
```

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?place%20dbpedia-owl%3ahighestPlace%20%3aMont_Blanc.%0D%0A%20%20%20?place%20rdf%3atype%20dbpedia-owl%3aMountainRange.%0D%0A%7D)

edit after comment: **filter**
It is not really clear what you want to filter (yago?), technically you can filter for example like this:

```
select * where {
   ?place dbpedia-owl:highestPlace :Mont_Blanc.
   ?place rdf:type dbpedia-owl:MountainRange.
   FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
     ?place ?pred ?obj
     Filter (regex(?obj, "yago"))
   }
}
```

this filters out results that have any `object` with 'yago' in its URL.

Comment: thanks, but it's not only Yago that I want to keep out. I want anything away that does not belong to Mountain Range class.

Comment: the first query already does that. It contains *ONLY* results that are of type 'mountain range'.

Comment: Nope, it contains "Mont Blanc massif" result. If you look at http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mont_Blanc_massif - it is of type Place. On the other hand, if you look at other three (eg http://dbpedia.org/page/Graian_Alps) - it is of type Mountain Range. I want those 3 and want Mont_Blanc_massif out.

Comment: What are you exactly referring to? if you look at the `rdf:type` both are `owl:Thing`, both are `dbpedia-owl:Place`, `dbpedia-owl:NaturalPlace`, and **both are** `dbpedia-owl:MountainRange`. None of them is 'canonical' or more important than the other.

Comment: when you see both the links I mentioned, you see that former is "An Entity of Type : place", while the later is "An Entity of Type : mountain range".

Comment: ok, now I understand. however, when querying with SPARQL, you should expect to find only the rdf-data (triples), not the (headline of the) html page dbpedia shows to browsers.

Comment: That's right, but this is not only for these records of Mountains that I am asking this question. It maybe for another mountains too, and such data can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the result from the previous answer, the appropriate query would be

```
select * where {
  ?mountain a dbpedia-owl:Mountain ;
            dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
            foaf:depiction ?depiction .
  ?range a dbpedia-owl:MountainRange ;
         dbpedia-owl:highestPlace ?mountain .
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"EN"))
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%2a+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fmountain+a+dbpedia-owl%3AMountain+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract+%3Fabstract+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++foaf%3Adepiction+%3Fdepiction+.%0D%0A++%3Frange+a+dbpedia-owl%3AMountainRange+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++dbpedia-owl%3AhighestPlace+%3Fmountain+.%0D%0A++FILTER%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%22EN%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

This selects mountains with English abstracts that have at least one depiction (or else the pattern wouldn't match) and for which there is some mountain range of which the mountain is the highest place.  Without the parts from the earlier question, if you just want to retrieve mountains that are the highest place of a range, you can use a query like this:

```
select * where {
  ?mountain a dbpedia-owl:Mountain .
  ?range a dbpedia-owl:MountainRange ;
         dbpedia-owl:highestPlace ?mountain .
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%2a+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fmountain+a+dbpedia-owl%3AMountain+.%0D%0A++%3Frange+a+dbpedia-owl%3AMountainRange+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++dbpedia-owl%3AhighestPlace+%3Fmountain+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Comment: Have to run at the moment, will update this later.  I'm actually having a bit of a problem getting ranges for most of the mountain peaks, and need to investigate a bit more…

Comment: If you look at Mont Blanc resource, there is a property named: "is dbpedia-owl:highestPlace of" - that is what I need. It says that Mont Blanc is hightest peak of some range. I need that range name. Sort of foreign key. And I need it only if it is of type Mountain Range, not Place or Thing or anything like that.

Comment: To explain my earlier comment:  my problem was that in reading the [Mont Blanc](http://dbpedia.org/page/Mont_Blanc) page, I saw that it "is dbpedia-owl:highestPlace of dbpedia:Western_Alps …" and had been writing my query with `?mountain dbpedia-owl:highestPlace ?range`.  That's backwards, of course;  it needed to be `?range dbpedia-owl:highestPlace ?mountain`.

Comment: Yes that works pretty much the way I want, except the filtering part. Look at: http://dbpedia.org/page/Mont_Blanc_massif - this is of type of Place, not MountainRange which I really want. Can it be done?

Comment: @NiravBhatt The SPARQL endpoint seems to be down at the moment, so I can't test additional queries right now.  Since the query above includes the pattern `?range a dbpedia-owl:MountainRange`, all the `?range`s that you get back are `dbpedia-owl:MountainRange`s.  In addition, `MountainRange` is a subclass of `NaturalPlace`, and I expect that `NaturalPlace` is a subclass of `Place`, so every `MountainRange` is also a `Place`.  If you don't want `Place`s, you can't have any `MountainRange`s.

Comment: The problem is, if Place turns out to be something other than a Mountainrange, it can be a river, a seabed, a city hall or a building. For obvious reasons, I don't want them.

Comment: @NiravBhatt Of course.  But the query _only_ returns things that _are_ mountain ranges, because of the pattern `?range a dbpedia-owl:MountainRange`.  While every `MountainRange` is a `Place`,  I don't expect that you'll see any `MountainRange` that is also a seabed, river, or building.

Comment: You seem to be right and the way data is organized must have this thing considered. I guess I am running with this query format and see if I encounter any unexpected data down the line. For now, thanks much for the effort!